# Argparse set_defaults for sub-parsers broken beyond Python 2.7.6?

Tags: python

I have an application using argparse which is broken by the latest versions of Python. I am no longer able to alter the defaults for sub-commands.

My app has various modules and an optional GUI. The GUI calls the modules via the sub-commands, and there is an ini file which may alter the argument defaults.

The GUI has created the parser and the sub-parsers, passing arguments as set by the GUI user. Options in the ini file may override the defaults in the sub-parsers.

This works in 2.7.6, but was broken by later releases due to an apparent change in argparse.

```
import argparse

# create the top-level parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true', dest='_foo')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='sub-command help')

# create the parser for the "a" command
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', help='a help')
parser_a.add_argument('--bar', type=int, default=0, dest='_bar')

#use ini file to alter default 
d_ini = {'_bar': '1'}
parser.set_defaults(**d_ini)

# parse some argument lists
print parser.parse_args(['a'])
```

In python 2.7.6 this prints as expected:

> > Namespace(_bar=1, _foo=False)

But in later releases, eg. 2.7.10 it prints

> > Namespace(_bar=0, _foo=False)

Am I using argparse incorrectly, because if this is a python bug it has persisted for a few releases now?

Do I need to process the ini file before adding the sub-parser defaults? This will be more cumbersome than my current approach as it will need to be done separately for each argument, and there are many. The python documentation for ArgumentParser.set_defaults explicitly states "Parser-level defaults can be particularly useful when working with multiple parsers", so it surprising if this facility has been compromised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the parser defaults must be applied to the sub parser of interest.  That is, in the code above, you should have:

```
# set defaults on parser_a
parser_a.set_defaults(**d_ini)
```

Setting defaults on `parser` does not set defaults on the sub parsers.  Instead it sets the default values for top level (global) arguments.   Why?  This way it is possible for the program to take an option `--bar`, and for multiple  subcommands `a`, `b`, `c` to also all take the option `--bar` with different defaults.

The former behaviour, in 2.7.6, which also appears in 3.3, should be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks. It may be worth noting that there seems to be an outstanding issue with regard to changing defaults of subcommands which share arguments with the main command, [link](http://bugs.python.org/issue9351)